# How can I guarantee that my mobile app is the only app can connects to my API [using OAuth2.0]

Tags: node.js, api, security, mobile

I have a Nodejs API, and I would like to secure it in a way that my Mobile App is the only application that can connect.

There is a private part of it , I think it's secured using access token. In the other hand I have a public endpoints, I thought about using Rate limiting and OAuth. I think this is an overkill because I need only my mobile app to connect to my API.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can add a function to your mobile app that calculates a time limited access token and sends it with the API requests.

Your API can use a similar function to verify that the API call came from your mobile app. It should check if access token is expired

Comment: I handled this already, the problem is that I want to make sure that all the request are coming from my mobile app only

Comment: There is no limitation for the number of users

Comment: Your API can check if the access token is valid. If it is not valid then it can reject the request

Comment: As I said before, I already handle this. but, I want to create a mechanism to allow me to check if the request comes only from my mobile phone. The access token can be sent from any other place.